# Not able to perform go-to-definition functionality in feature file to navigate to step definition file in a protractor-cucumber framework

Tags: visual-studio, protractor, cucumber

Go-to-definition functionality not working on vs-code.

I have installed **cucumber(gherkin) full support** plugin.

**Steps to replicate**: Right click on steps on feature file and select go to definition.

Feature file

```
Gherkin code : When user access the Application
```

Step definition file

```
When('user access the Application', async function () {

  await PageObject.open();

});
```

**Expected**: It should navigate to step-definitions file.

project folder structure

[image]

settings.json
[image]

Comment: Please post the Gherkin code and step definition code as well.

Comment: I think you need to configure the plugin, not only just install it.

Comment: @yong can you please help me with the plugin.. I have been searching for it , didn't find yet.

Answer (score 5):

1. install plugin:  Cucumber (Gherkin) Full Support (Alexander Krechik)
2. create a folder: `.vscode` **under project folder (don't in any subfolder)**
3. create a file: `settings.json` under `.vscode`
4. In vscode, reopen the folder where `.vscode` insides to make settings take effect.

Following is the example project on my local and the **go to definition** worked well on it.

**project folder structure**
[image]
**settings.json**

```
{
    "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
        "steps/*js"
    ],
    "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "features/*feature", 
    "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": true
}
```

(Remember change to your step definition and feature file path)

Comment: did not work for me.. I have created the .vscode folder under my main folder then to just check I moved it to src folder , it didn't worked in both the cases.

Comment: show me you project folder structure and your `.vscode/setting.json`

Comment: images of folder structure and settings.json file added to the query.

Comment: move `.vscode` to `test` folder, change settings.json to `src/main/step-definitions/*js`, then reopen test folder in VSCode.   VSCode only respects `.vscode`  that under the root folder it opened.  `.vscode` in subfolder of opened folder seems to be ignored by VSCode.

Comment: I tried keeping it both the places earlier as well, now I have moved it to test folder and changed the step-def path as provided by you, Still not working at my end.

Comment: I post folder structure and settings.json of my project which `go to definition` worked well on it.

Comment: Thank you so much Yong .. With your folder structure I understood where I was missing .. It is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

- Install cucumber extension and click gear(settings)icon in VS code.
- Click Extensions/cucumber and click "Edit in settings.json"
  hyperlink.
- In the settings.json file, paste the below code and save the file.

```json
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "playwright.reuseBrowser": true,
    "cucumber.features": [        
        "src/test/feature/*.feature",
    ],
    "cucumber.glue": [
        "src/test/steps/*.ts"
    ],
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "never",
    "editor.fontSize": 16,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Light",
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 16,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "editor.comments.ignoreEmptyLines": false
}
```

Note: Change the path of your feature file and step definitions based on your folder structure.